# Use RegEx to pop out multiple alphanumeric strings from URL in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have been trying to figure this out but my limited regex knowledge is getting in the way.  I am wondering if we can use regex/python to remove alphanumeric strings from a given URL.  These alphanumeric strings will only contain **a** through **f** and **0** to **9**.  For example:

```
/cab/user/core1/bdc49fd8/bd77de6ce
```

I want to use regex to get:

```
/cab/user/core1
```

I have this working where I can take off the last alphanumeric string, but it fails when there are more than one in the same URL:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\/[a-f0-9]*$', ' ', "/cab/user/core1/bdc49fd8"))
```

results in:

```
/cab/user/core1
```

but:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\/[a-f0-9]*$', ' ', "/cab/user/core1/bdc49fd8/bd77de6ce"))
```

results in:

```
/cab/user/core1/bdc49fd8
```

Is there a way to remove all occurrences of the specific alphanumeric pattern from the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'(?:/[a-fA-Z0-9]*)+$', '', "/cab/user/core1/bdc49fd8/bd77de6ce"))
# => /cab/user/core1
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VR0eHp) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dc4UB9/1).

The `(?:/[a-f0-9]*)+$` pattern matches 1 or more repetitions of a sequence of patterns defined in the [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do), `/` and then 0+ alphanumeric chars, and after them the end of string position should follow.

Comment: (?:/[a-f0-9]*)+$ works perfectly- thank you for the quick response and explanation!